# How to authenticate to salesforce API from bubble.io

Tags: salesforce, bubble.io

I am working through bubble.io to Salesforce REST API integration via token - not username password flow. Have enabled backend API calls, installed the bubble API plugin, reviewed the associated docs and trying to understand how you combine auth step with subsequent database actions. i.e. get a token and then include in subsequent database action.

If anyone has any pointers or sample resources that would help me to understand how to combine the two steps into an authenticated Salesforce database action it would be really appreciated.